# A process just won't die

Tags: linux, debian, python, process

For context: I have been playing with stable diffusion on my home server lately, but because my GPU is pretty old, the process often crashes and hangs when I try to go too far. Usually, I'd just kill it with `ctrl+C` and restart the process.
But today,no matter what I do, it seems like the process refuses to die.

I've looked it up a bit, it is not a "zombie" process, both `sudo top` and `ps ux | awk '{if($8=="Z") print}'` confirm it, but I cannot kill it with a `sudo kill <PID> -9`

If it's relevant, the process is a python virtual environment (.venv)

I can, of course, just reboot the whole machine, but I'd like to understand why it's happening, and how to prevent/fix it

Edit: It happened once again, this time I didn't `ctrl+C` before trying `sudo kill <PID> -9` and the process closed quickly. I'm guessing the `ctrl+C` tries to close the process, but hangs somewhere, so the `kill -9` doesn't take effect properly. If someone knows why it happens, I'd still appreciate the explanation

Comment: It is difficult to handle Ctrl-C in Python programs correctly. Some Python programs accidentally ignore the interrupt.

Comment: I see, so is it better to use `kill <PID>` ? Maybe starting with `-15` and going to `-9` if that doesn't work

Comment: A Ctrl-C corresponds to `kill -2` (SIGINT). Just like SIGTERM/15 it can be ignored by the process. SIGKILL/9 should always work because it's handled by the scheduler and never reaches the process, but I have seen delightful kernel bugs where this too failed. If process termination is hanging, this could be an indication that a parent process is waiting for subprocesses to complete. You can inspect subprocess via a command like `pstree -pT <PID>`. Try killing childs before the parent.

Comment: it only returns itself
```pstree -pT 79322``` returns
```python(79322)
```

Comment: maybe  you can use strace command to trace system calls and signals of a process, you can use the command "strace -p PID"